# Docker inside an internal network fails to fetch google.com through TOR proxy

Tags: docker, networking, proxy, devops, tor

When I isolate my app from the internet, it fails to fetch google.com through tor proxy,
but when I add it to the internet network, it works and the request does go through the tor proxy. I'm really confused by this. What am I doing wrong?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  tor-proxy:
    image: dperson/torproxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - no-internet
      - internet
   
  app:
    depends_on: [tor-proxy]
    build: ./
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - no-internet
      - internet # if i comment this out, fetch() will result in ETIMEDOUT

networks:
  no-internet:
    driver: bridge
    internal: true

  internet:
    driver: bridge
    internal: false
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

index.js

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

import { SocksProxyAgent } from 'socks-proxy-agent';

(async () => {
    const agent = new SocksProxyAgent('socks5://tor-proxy:9050');

    const res = await fetch('https://google.com', { agent });
})();
```

Comment: Does node have everything it needs to run without network access? E.g. does the import hit the network, or does fetch do a DNS resolution? I've been able to implement similar solutions with an http proxy and go app using the same network layout.

Comment: with the same setup, if I exec into the app container and do

`echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "http://tor-proxy:8118/";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy`,

`apt-get update` succeeds downloading packages. But `curl https://google.com` fails

Comment: `root@242b5b48c757:/usr/src/app# curl -x socks5://tor-proxy:9050 https://google.com/`


`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com`
`root@242b5b48c757:/usr/src/app# curl -x socks5://tor-proxy:9050 https://142.250.217.110:80`
`curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`
(142.250.217.110 is the IP that google.com resolves to)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue different situation. Only found partial shitty answers so here's another but this one doesn't require discombobulating your iptables or in my situation, my teams.

ANSWER: use "driver: ipvlan" on the internal network and the containers name as hostname when making requests https://docs.docker.com/network

EXAMPLE: curl -v --socks5-hostname tor-proxy:9050 google.com

EXPLANATION: I don't have one but warn external network access may still be possible by other means. i would also appreciate an explanation but we probably wont get one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the DNS lookup. If you switch from [socks5 to socks5h](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-socks-proxy-agent/blob/5bed1f11aea26320f1a4ddc2664d66aaaaa78611/src/index.ts#L60) you'll skip the client side DNS lookup, which isn't available in an isolated network:

```
    const agent = new SocksProxyAgent('socks5h://tor-proxy:9050');
```

And from the comments, if you want curl to use an https proxy:

```sh
export https_proxy=http://tor-proxy:8118/
curl https://google.com
```

or for curl to use the socks5 proxy without doing local DNS resolution:

```sh
curl --socks5-hostname tor-proxy:9050 https://google.com
```

Comment: That works, but some requests result in ETIMEDOUT, why does it fail to lookup domains through the tor-proxy? :/ I want to keep the network isolated, but still be able to make DNS lookups.